# How to create array of JSON object from another array using Angular js

Tags: javascript, angularjs, arrays, json

hello everyone i have the following issue, 
i have an array of JSON object like this :

```
$scope.array_one=[

  {
    "field1": "value 1",
    "field2": "value 2",
    "field3": "value 3",
    "field4": "value 4",
    "field5": "value 5",
    "field6": "value 6",
    "field7": "value 7",
    "field8": "value 8"
  },
  {
    "field1": "value 1",
    "field2": "value 2",
    "field3": "value 3",
    "field4": "value 4",
    "field5": "value 5",
    "field6": "value 6",
    "field7": "value 7",
    "field8": "value 8"
  }

  ...
]
```

i want to create an new array (from the $scope.array_one) that contains only objects with 3 fields

something like this :

```
[

  {

    "field2": "value 2",
    "field3": "value 3",
    "field6": "value 6",
    "field8": "value 8"
  },
  {
    "field2": "value 2",
    "field3": "value 3",
    "field6": "value 6",
    "field8": "value 8"
  }

  ...
]
```

anyone can guide me on how to achieve this, i 'm using Angular js.

Regards !

Comment: Have you tried anything yourself ? Try using `Array.filter` to achieve this. I think it should be sufficient.

Comment: @ShivenSinha i want to extract only the field2,field3,field6,field8 from the array_one , something like projection ..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could map the wanted parts with a destruction.

```js
var $scope = { array_one: [{ field1: "value 1", field2: "value 2", field3: "value 3", field4: "value 4", field5: "value 5", field6: "value 6", field7: "value 7", field8: "value 8" }, { field1: "value 1", field2: "value 2", field3: "value 3", field4: "value 4", field5: "value 5", field6: "value 6", field7: "value 7", field8: "value 8" }] },
    result = $scope.array_one.map(
        ({ field2, field3, field6, field8 }) => ({ field2, field3, field6, field8 })
    );

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `Array#Map()` to create a new array by returning a new object

```js
let array_one = [
  {
    "field1": "value 1",
    "field2": "value 2",
    "field3": "value 3",
    "field4": "value 4",
    "field5": "value 5",
    "field6": "value 6",
    "field7": "value 7",
    "field8": "value 8"
  },
  {
    "field1": "value 1",
    "field2": "value 2",
    "field3": "value 3",
    "field4": "value 4",
    "field5": "value 5",
    "field6": "value 6",
    "field7": "value 7",
    "field8": "value 8"
  }
];

let newArray = array_one.map(f => ({
  field2 : f.field1,
  field3 : f.field3,
  field6 : f.field6,
  field8 : f.field8,
}));

console.log(newArray);
```

Comment: hi @Weedoze ithink this is a typeScript syntax for Angular 2 , i'm using Angular js 1.X !

Comment: @Ali The code provided in the answer is totally not typescript and can either be used for Angular or AngularJS. This is pure ES6

Comment: you are right  , it works fine thank you so much for your time